# Font Awesome not filling menu bar

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

In my menu bar I have a search icon using font awesome. every item in menu bar is filling it but search's height is about 80-85% of it`s parent. this is my html code

```html
 <html>

  <head>
      <title>main page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
<style>
 body
{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}

ul
{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  background-color:#CC6666;
  overflow:hidden;
  list-style-type:none;
  font-size:18;
  font-weight:bold;
}

li{float:right;}

li a
{
  display:inline-block;
    display:inline-block;
      text-decoration:none;
      color:white;
      text-align:center;
      padding:12px 16px;
      font-weight:400;
      padding-right:15px;
  }
  li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn{
      background-color:#666666;
      margin:0px;

  }
  .active{
      background-color:#666666;
  }
   
.search{
  float:left;
}
</style>
  </head>
<body>
   <div class="posi">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="active" herf="home">خانه</a></li>

    <li>
      <a href="#">سوالات متداول</a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="#">عضویت در سایت</a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a herf="#">معرفی</a></li>
    <li class="search"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a></li>
 </ul>
    </div>
</html>
```

[This is what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrSGJ.jpg)

how can I fix this?

Comment: Adjust the font-size of the icon such that it fills the space you desire (try ~17px)

Comment: I am not getting your requirement.

Comment: do you want to reduce the size of search icon...

Comment: When you hover on search icon it's not filling the parent @Bhawna

Comment: That is not working @haxxxton

Comment: try to give to item li a in your css a margin-bottom:-1px;

Comment: Can you please check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/fjaedwaL/

Comment: li a {margin-bottom:-1px; .... }

Comment: Your code is working fine in my browser (Chrome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add:

```
line-height: 1;
```

to

```
li a
```

Comment: Thanks. But what is line-height? And how this fixes my problem?

Comment: From the MDN website: On block level elements, the line-height property specifies the minimum height of line boxes within the element. In your case, fot-awesome is using that line-height and your box wasn't matching that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a chrome-specific bug, as with safari and firefox there doesn't seem to be a problem. If anyone else can verify this or refute this please let me know. I'm using Chrome Version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit) Anyways - here is a chrome-specific solution

```js
// jQuery to add css class "chrome-fix" which changes height of ".search a" to 24 px instead of 22 px
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Chrome/") != -1) {
$(".search a").addClass(".chrome-fix");
}
```

```css
body
{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}

ul
{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  background-color:#CC6666;
  overflow:hidden;
  list-style-type:none;
  font-size:18px;
  font-weight:bold;
}

li{float:right;}

li a
{
  display:inline-block;
    display:inline-block;
      text-decoration:none;
      color:white;
      text-align:center;
      padding:12px 16px;
      font-weight:400;
      padding-right:15px;
  }
  li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn{
      background-color:#666666;
      margin:0px;

  }
  .active{
      background-color:#666666;
  }
   
.search{
  float:left;
  height:41px;
}
.chrome-fix {
    height:24px;
}
```

```html
<html>

  <head>
      <title>main page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>

  </head>
<body>
   <div class="posi">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="active" herf="home">خانه</a></li>

    <li>
      <a href="#">سوالات متداول</a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="#">عضویت در سایت</a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a herf="#">معرفی</a></li>
    <li class="search"><a href="#" class="chrome-fix"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a></li>
 </ul>
    </div>
</html>
```